# Light blue border around bottom, left, and right of Gravatar on user page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On the user pages there's now a light blue border around the bottom, left, and right of the Gravatar:

[image]

I suspect that the border area around the image has grown and caused this - I don't remember the border being right up next to the text on the right before. I could be mistaken though.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by transparencies - if you have transparencies in your Gravatar, [then it'll be rendered with a specific background color](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101452/eeeek-gravatar-images-now-have-a-background-color-is-this-necessary) based on the site. In Ask Different, it looks decidedly poor because of it not matching the rounded border piece, though.

Until a fix is provided, you could use a workaround by resizing your image to fix the full size, rather than just a partial fit.

Answer (score 0):

This will be fixed with the next deploy.

For some reason Ask Different gravatars were styled to be slightly smaller than gravatars on every other site in the network.

There may be some additional style tweaks, as the user page is looking a tad crowded with the bigger icon...